# Add Swagger UI to a custom .NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I want to integrate Swagger UI into my C# .Net Web API project. This is different from a traditional Web API project where you can install a tool like SwashBuckle, which then picks up the HTTP routes defined in your controller classes and creates the UI.

What I have is a custom implementation which generates the OpenAPI/Swagger 3.0 yaml files for different routes.

I have a route defined in a generic controller file which accepts a variable -

```
http://localhost:8000/myapp/swagger/{document_name}
```

where document_name is a variable. My code takes this variable and generates the custom documentation based on this value.

```
http://localhost:8000/myapp/swagger/sedan
http://localhost:8000/myapp/swagger/suv
```

In the example above my code would return a different Open API spec for sedan and suv.

As of now the URL simply returns Open API 3.0 YAML spec in plain text. What I want to be able to do is to be able to have this file represented in the Swagger UI similar to this -

http://petstore.swagger.io/

Is this possible? Can I use Swashbuckle for this? Do I need to do a custom implementation to host the Swagger UI? What's the best way?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the OpenAPI/Swagger 3.0 yaml file(s) all you need is the UI and you have a few options:

- Copy the UI files to your server.
  This will give you the most flexibility, allowing you to customize using the [configuration parameters](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md)  
  You only need the files in the dist folder:
  https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist
- Use the petstore or any other existing UI and pass your file as parameter, like this:
  http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/swagger/swagger_aws.json

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to host the UI in .NET OWIN project. I am not sure how can I serve up the Swagger UI dist folder through OWIN? Any ideas?

Comment: @sandunes90 sounds like another question for StackOverflow. ... How can I serve static content with OWIN

Comment: I did put it up - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204484/host-swagger-ui-3-0-dist-folder-using-owin.

Comment: Following up on this, I was able to use "UseStaticFiles" option in OWIN. Is there a better way to do this where instead of the file, the Swagger "Index.html" would accept the YAML/JSON definition text? Instead of using the path to the definition file?

Comment: @sandunes90 you mean like: http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/swagger/swagger_aws.json

Comment: Yes but instead of using the existing UI, I'd like to be able to use the index.html UI file on my server for the same purpose.

Comment: @sandunes90 so you want to reinvent the swagger-ui?