# Host Swagger UI 3.0 Dist folder using OWIN

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, owin, swagger-ui

I want to self-host the Swagger UI Dist folder on a Web Server using OWIN. I cannot use IIS to host Swagger UI.

Most OWIN guides only talk about hosting Web API projects.

How can I do that?

The reason I want to do this is that I already have a separate project that generates the Open API/Swagger v3.0 schema docs. So I have the specs ready, I just need a way to host/show them on the Swagger UI. And this Swagger UI project needs to be self-hosted.

See this -

[Add Swagger UI to a custom .NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993300/add-swagger-ui-to-a-custom-net-web-api)

Comment: Swagger UI is just like any other static files... https://www.google.com/search?q=owin+serving+static+files